# WebClient SSL Single Sign on Proxy

Tags: c#, ssl, single-sign-on

I'm building an AJAX proxy page to pull the information from a SSL Single Sign on Site.  Unfortunately I feel like i'm getting stuck.  I've tried using webclient and HttpWebRequest but i can't seem to get past the initial page.

I'm catch the a link click action and passing the URL of the link to my proxy page.

```
$("#Frame").load("/ProxyAjax?url=" + serializedData);
```

and executing the following code

```
string redirectUrl = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["url"]);
Uri myURI = new Uri(redirectUrl);
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

wc.Headers.Add("Cookie", Request.Headers["Cookie"]);

vd.String = wc.DownloadString(redirectUrl);
```

Have the page I'm calling is executing a redirect and I get stuck somewhere between.  Any ideas of how to resolve this?

Comment: Is the sso server redirecting to a resource provider perhaps?

Comment: it might be but one would think that the redirect would be caught.  I've tried using the HttpWebRequest with AllowAutoRedirect = false and it seems to keep looping

Comment: Take fiddler and see the http request/responses on the wire...